# Missing Argument in for __construct

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I get this error where I run :

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MYDATABASE', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$Manager = new CompanyManager($db);
$Manager->getList();
```

ERROR :

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for Company::__construct(), called in /.../CompanyManager.class.php on line 53 and defined in /.../Company.class.php on line 17
```

Here is the part of CompanyManager.class.php :

```
  public function getList()
  {
    $Company = array();

    $q = $this->_db->query('SELECT id, statut, company, activity, source, secteur, comments, offer_date, entry_date, type_ope, gestionnaire, next_step FROM prospect ORDER BY id');

    while ($donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $Company[] = new Company($donnees);
    }

    return $Company;
  }
```

And here is Company.class.php (interesting part) :

```
<?php
class Company
{
    private $_id;
    private $_statut;
    private $_company;
    private $_activity;
    private $_source;
    private $_secteur;
    private $_comments;
    private $_offerDate;
    private $_entryDate;
    private $_typeOpe;
    private $_gestionnaire;
    private $_nextStep;

    public function __construct($id, $statut, $company, $activity, $source, $secteur, $comments, $offerDate, $entryDate, $typeOpe, $gestionnaire, $nextStep)
    {
        $this->setId($id);
        $this->setStatut($statut);
        $this->setCompany($company);
        $this->setActivity($activity);
        $this->setSource($source);
        $this->setSecteur($secteur);
        $this->setComments($comments);
        $this->setOfferDate($offerDate);
        $this->setEntryDate($entryDate);
        $this->setTypeOpe($typeOpe);
        $this->setGestionnaire($gestionnaire);
        $this->setNextStep($nextStep);
    }
```

BIG thanks for everyone who gonna try to give me a hand ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function getList()
  {
    $Company = array();

    $q = $this->_db->query('SELECT id, statut, company, activity, source, secteur, comments, offer_date, entry_date, type_ope, gestionnaire, next_step FROM prospect ORDER BY id');

    while ($donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $Company[] = new Company($donnees['id'], $donnees['statut'], $donnees['company'], $donnees['activity'], $donnees['source'], .....);
    }

    return $Company;
  }
```

Otherwise you can do this

```
    public function __construct(array $data) {
       $this->setId($data['id']);
       .
       .
       .
       .
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, where do `$id`, `$statut` etc come from in your while loop? I think they need to be `$donnees['id']` etc

Comment: @martynthewolf I give an example.where is the mistakes

Comment: while ($donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $Company[] = new Company($id, $statut, $company, $activity, $source, .....);
    }

This is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Well your Company class expects all the parameters in the __construct() parameter list to be passed. None of them are optional.

It looks like you are passing an array to your Company class at the minute, you need to pass each value according to your parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implicitly pass variables to Company's constructor:

```
public function getList()
  {
    $Company = array();

    $q = $this->_db->query('SELECT id, statut, company, activity, source, secteur, comments, offer_date, entry_date, type_ope, gestionnaire, next_step FROM prospect ORDER BY id');

    while (list($id, $status, $company, /*etc*/) = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $Company[] = new Company($id, $status, $company, /*etc*/);
    }

    return $Company;
  }
```